# R: how to make passing of arguments using ... to multiple functions well-defined?

Tags: r

**V1**: Suppose functions `f(x, ...)` and `g(x , ...)` can be passed different arguments. If I were to define a new function using both of them, can I make the passing of arguments via the `...` operator well-defined? As a simple example:

```
f1 = function(x, n = 1) x + n
g1 = function(x, m = 1) x + m
f  = function(x, ...) f1(x, ...)
g  = function(x, ...) g1(x, ...)

h = function(x, ...) {

  fgList = list()
  fgList[["f"]] = f(x, ...)
  fgList[["g"]] = g(x, ...)
  return(fgList)
}

h(1:4)
#  $f
#  [1] 2 3 4 5

#  $g
#  [1] 2 3 4 5

h(1:4, n = 2)
#  Error in g1(x, ...) : unused argument (n = 2)
```

The argument `n` is being passed down to functions `f` and `g`, but it is only well-defined for function `f`. I want to mitigate against this.

**V2:** If they are functions that I have defined, then Hong Ooi's solution below works perfectly.

Can this solution be extended for pre-defined functions which don't have a `...` argument or equivalently, can a `...` argument be 'added' to a predefined function which doesn't have one? For example:

```
h = function(x, ...) mean(x, ...) * median (x, ...)
h(1:4, test = 1)
##  Error in median(x, ...) : unused argument (test = 1)
```

Comment: V2: you can always do `mean(x, ...) * {function(y, ...) median(y)}(x, ...)` but I find it deceiving to define `...` if the function doesn't make use of those extra arguments, so i'd use it with care.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have multiple versions of `...` in the one environment. What you can do, however, is give each of your called sub-functions a `...` argument *of their own*. This means they will ignore any parameters passed down that don't match their own formal arguments.

```
f1 = function(x, n = 1, ...) x + n
g1 = function(x, m = 1, ...) x + m

> h(1:4, n = 2)
$f
[1] 3 4 5 6

$g
[1] 2 3 4 5
```

Edit to answer added question: you can make a new version of `median`, which will override the predefined function when you call it in your own code. (Due to how R namespaces work, other predefined functions will still use the existing version.)

```
median <- function(x, na.rm=FALSE, ...)
base::median(x, na.rm)  # function median exported from base package
```

Comment: +1. Thank gawd someone was able to figure out what was being asked.

Comment: plus one to the answer and to @DWin's comment.  Not sure how you got that from the question..   Well done

Comment: @ HongOoi: thank you very much for your answer. @DWin: being relatively new to R, I thought it would be better to ask my question through an example. After reading HongOoi's *helpful* reply and taking on board your comments, I have edited my question accordingly – though from the histrionic nature of your comment, I'm surprised you haven't done this already.

Comment: @Mullefa: I wasn't complaining about you R abilities, but rather your failing to explain what was desired. To your edit: What will a new version of `median` with "added ... arguments" be able to do? You have not explained the goals of this effort or the criteria for judging success in natural language.

Comment: To add to the general confustication here, I've run into this problem off and on when I've written some function which calls several other functions.  I usually find it easier to identify the potentially conflicting arguments and give them default values (since they're not part of "..." they don't get passed where they shouldn't).  There's always the trick, just inside the top-level function, of defining `dotlist<-list(...)` and playing games to see what named items exist there.